# forwarding url parameters to the next url

Tags: php, hyperlink, parameter-passing

Using PHP (for the first time in my life) and working in a CMS environment without access to the back-end PHP pages or code, I created a form on one page that places four parameters into the url of the next page to which the form send its data.

Here is the form page:

http://CMSDetroit.org/480

Here is the url the form generates:

http://www.chambermusicdetroit.org/422?School=formdata&Grade=formdata&Teacherformdata=&Handle=formdata

I need to collect the parameter information from the url and pass it on to the url of the next page after this one, either by putting a command into every link on the page (422), or through some other more efficient method.

I've tried all sorts of things and keep coming up dry...help!?!

Comment: What are the next pages?

Comment: Confusing question. How are you using PHP without access to the PHP?

Comment: hjpotter92L: the page has links to three pages -  http://CMSDetroit.org/423, /435 or /437

Answer (score -1):

For PHP see [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and more specifically QUERY_STRING

Then with that I'm not sure how you are invoking the next page? maybe with header?

> header('Location: http://www.example.com/?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING');
>
> exit;

Point being it is just one large string.  If you don't know already you use [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) and key to extract the individual values or if you want you can use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) on the QUERY STRING